# What's a symbol for "can be true but not guaranteed to be true"

Tags: notation

I'm trying to show a formula involving dot products equaling zero. Obviously, the dot product "can" equal zero if the angle between two vectors is 90 degrees, but it could also not be zero in any other case. What symbol can I use to show this?

Comment: $\Phi(x)$ "can be true but not guaranteed to be true" might be expressed as $\exists x\,\Phi(x)\land \exists x\,\neg\Phi(x)$

Comment: Why do you want a symbol for something like this? There is basically no statement made.

Comment: It's a good question.  I'd personally just state: "in general, $V\cdot W\ne 0$" and maybe, if approriate (as it would be in this case, but not nescessarily always) I'd make a cooment about when it is true.

Answer (score 0):

[Modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) contains the diamond operator for expressing things like "P is possibly true".  But outside of formal logic it's hardly ever used.

Answer (score 0):

If I go somewhat off-question as this will work for this case specifically. 
But this would make your task much easier (as the symbols etc. in other answers and comments are not very friendly sort of).

You can say that $$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}  \in [-ab, ab]$$

Note that it satisfies your question as $0$ lies within $[-x,x]$.